# Call different UserForms in a Program

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am creating a program to make some filters from a UserForm (but there will be many UserForms) with checkboxes. The program works like this:

- Choose some Checkboxes from a UserForm
- Click a CommandButton called Next
- The Filter loads with the following code:

Excel VBA Code

```
Sub Filtrarvar(ByVal j As Integer, ByVal k As Integer, _
               ByVal col As Integer, ByVal Userf As String)

    Dim Countercheck As Integer    
    Countercheck = 0    
    i = j    
    n = j

    Dim Lista() As String    
    longitud = k - j    
    ReDim Lista(longitud)

    Do While i <= k    
        If UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True Then    
            ContaTic = ContaTic + 1    
        End If    
        i = i + 1    
    Loop

    If ContaTic = 0 Or ContaTic = longitud + 1 Then    
        Sheets("Aux_total").Range(Cells(1, 1), _
               Cells(UltLinea, UltColumna)).AutoFilter Field:=col, Criteria1:="<>"    
    ElseIf ContaTic >= 1 Then    
        arr = 0    
        Do While n <= k    
            If UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & n).Value = True Then    
                Value = UserForm2.Controls("CheckBox" & n).Caption

                Lista(arr) = Value    
                arr = arr + 1    
           End If    
        n = n + 1    
        Loop

        Sheets("Aux_total").Range(Cells(1, 1), _
               Cells(UltLinea, UltColumna)).AutoFilter Field:=col, Criteria1:=Lista, _
               Operator:=xlFilterValues    
    End If    
End Sub
```

And I want to call the Program like this:

```
Filtrarvar 1, 6, 4, "Europe"
```

What I would like to know is how to change the code from `UserForm2` to *Europe* and so forth? I would like to do that for each UserForm/Continent.

Comment: 1.) Build 1 form.  2.) Give it a property for whatever "Europe" would indicate in your example (consider using an `Enum`).  3.) Configure the form at runtime based on the passed property value before you `.Show` it. 4.) Generate [hard instances instead of using the default instance](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms/19036/best-practices#t=201611212133242937607).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `VBA.Forms` which behaves similarly to a collection. However, you must load in the name of an existing userform then reference it by index.

```
Sub Filtrarvar(ByVal j As Integer, ByVal k As Integer, _
               ByVal col As Integer, ByVal Userf As String)

    ' LOAD CURRENT Userf value (i.e., Eurpoe)
    VBA.UserForms.Add Userf
    ...

    ' REFERENCE USERFORM BY INDEX
    Do While i <= k    
        If VBA.UserForms(0).Controls("CheckBox" & i).Value = True Then  
            ContaTic = ContaTic + 1    
        End If    
        i = i + 1    
    Loop
    ...

End Sub
```